# Max number of images IE 9 can load in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Is there a maximum number of images, using the image tag, that IE 9 can load in one HTML file?

I'm loading 60 to 120 images (1675x2638) in one HTML file. I've noticed that after the the 55th image, the images are not being loaded anymore. The "broken image" label is reflected in the image tag.

In my HTML file, I loaded 10 images first then when they scan down. I load the succeeding images via AJAX, until all the images are loaded.

Am I missing any restrictions for IE 9 in load HTML content (ie. images)?

Comment: I don't think so... check not to get the response at ajax from cache. You might got an error first time now you keep loading it. Also try to load them directly in the html without ajax. If that's working try adding a delay between ajax requests. Server might treat your 10+ requests as spam and decline some of them.

Comment: This only happens in IE 9 though. Chrome, Safari and Firefox it works fine. I called the image multiple times but I still get a broken image. @zozo what do you mean by " try to load them directly in the html without ajax?" Thanks!

Comment: IE has some strange behavior by default :). Yet 60 images is not that much. At least it does not seem too much for me. What I wanted to say is that instead of making ajax requests for each just make a blank page and put them into img tags. Yeah, is not a good way to load them but is just a test. See if they are loaded. If yes you know the script is the problem. If no... well... that sucks :).

Answer (score 0):

Naturally there is some kind of limit somewhere, as the browser can't load an infinite number of images in a finite system.

Most limitations would however be way higher than just 55 images. The browser might for example have a limit of 4000 million (2<sup>32</sup>) elements in a page.

The most likely limit would be the amount of disk space allowed for the cache, which also leads to that it's actually more likely that the problem is that the cache is too large than too small. Some versions of IE determines the default space for the cache as a percentage of the available disk space, so if the disk is large that value becomes more than the cache can actually handle.

You should check how much cache space is allowed in the browser, and set it to a reasonable value (for example 100 MB) if it is too high or too low.

Comment: I have 200GB of free HD space. Right now it's 205MB for the Temporary Internet Files. Is that the settings that needs to be changed @Guffa? If it is, I don't think I can change the settings in behalf of the user. Thanks!

Comment: @NorbsKnight: That is a reasonable setting, so then that's not the problem. 60 high resolution images *is* a lot, using about 800 MB of memory, so it might be a memory limitation if the browser tries to keep all the images in memory instead of keeping them in the cache.